# Is Gibbs free energy not zero always?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

The heat q we provide is change in enthalpy. Also we measure entropy by the heat we provide with respect to Temperature(S=Q/T).

In gibbs equation,
dG= dH-TdS
dH is the energy we supply. Also TdS is also the energy we provide.
This makes me think that dG=0. But why it is not?

Answer (score 1):

If the system is in equilibrium you have $dG = 0$. In this event the pressure is constant and you have $dq_P = dH$, if you replace in the definition of $dG$ you have

dG = dq - TdS

so it is correct that dG = 0 since TdS = $\delta q$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for dG is incorrect.  It should read $$dG=dH-TdS-SdT$$.  When combined with the equation $dH=TdS+VdP$, you then get$$dG=VdP-SdT$$At constant temperature, this reduces to $dG=VdP$

Comment: but at constant pressure dP = 0.